# Is base64 encoding always one to one

Tags: encoding, base64

Is it possible to obtain two identical encoded values for two different inputs to the Base64 encoding algorithm?

Let's use another algorithm for example, a function that replaces underscores with the letter X.

```
Foo_Bar = FooXBar
FooXBar = FooXBar
```

Can this sort of thing ever happen with Base64 encoding?

Comment: This might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225750/is-it-possible-to-get-collisions-with-base64-encoding-decoding

Comment: .. right, but in the opposite direction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it cannot happen. Base64 is a lossless conversion (and it even needs a 33% space more). In math terms, the Base64 function is an [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

Note how [HTTP basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) use this encoding for the username and the password. Anyone can get the original strings from the encoded one, and for this reason this authentication should be used only under HTTPS.

You can find more details on Base64 also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: Note that while collisions are not possible, base64 is not a bijection but only an injection - the same data can be encoded in multiple ways in base64 (due to padding at the end at least, but also padding in the middle of the string and whitespace).

Answer (score 3):

No, base64 is just a way of encoding binary data as printable characters.

Strictly speaking, it's just a number system, like binary (base 2), decimal(base 10), or hexadecimal (base 16).  Just as you can convert losslessly between those you can with base 64.  In fact, mathematically bases are irrelevant, and are only used for notation and human use, math is equivalent no matter what base you use.